# Invoke script under scripts folder from grails controller

Tags: grails, groovy

In my Grails application, from controller I am trying to invoke a script present under scripts folder

**Controller Code**

```
def invokeScript(){
        def bg= ["groovy","scripts/masterScript.groovy", request.JSON]
        bg.execute();
        render("Script Invoked")
    }
```

**masterScript.groovy**

```
println("Master Script Invoked with arguements " + args[0]);
```

**Expected Output**

On Console: "Master Script Invoked with arguements "
Response: Script Invoked

**Actual Output**

No message printed on console but Response is accurate "Script Invoked"

If i invoke the masterScript explicitly from command prompt it works correctly and prints on console.

Please help and clarify the following

1. Why I don't see any message from script on console when invoked from Controller
2. Can I set a debug break point in the script present inside Scripts Folder as it is a async call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.execute()` returns [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance, that have methods to access output, errors and status code.

So answer for '1': because you don't copy output of a command to your console. See docs: http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management

And for '2': you cannot, because you're calling script as external process. If you want to evaluate Groovy script, rather than calling plain external command it's better to use [GroovyScriptEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html)

Comment: You made my day. Was struggling with it for 3 hours now. Thank you so much. It worked perfectly.